# document.getElementById("idt").textContent is not removing the existing text

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to change text content in a

tag of my html on click event , but the new text content just adds to the old text instead of replacing .

```js
document.getElementById("div_Container").addEventListener("click", function Typer(){
    var index = 0;
    var text ="Hello there, I'm a college student and I have a keen eye for whacky and cheeky animations.";
    var speed = 60;
      
    function textEffect() {
        if (index < text.length) {
            document.getElementById("typing_Text").textContent += text.charAt(index);
            index++;
            setTimeout(textEffect, speed);
        }
        
    }
    textEffect();
    
}, {once : true});
```

```html
<div id="div_Container" class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-start">
        <p id="typing_Text">Click here to learn about me. </p>
</div>
```

i have tried replacing textContent with innerHtml .

Comment: What do you think `+=` does? Isn't that exactly what it is supposed to do: **keep** the previous content, and **append** the new content? If that is not what you want, then why not just assign with `=` or at least initialise with `=`?

Comment: It looks like you just need to set the initial textContent to an empty string before starting.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you should do it if you want to remove the text before inserting the new one, just add that one line before the textEffect function. Just made a [fiddle here](https://codejs.com/qodejs?file=524263) with my solution in case you want to try it out. Hope this is what you are looking for.

```
document.getElementById("div_Container").addEventListener("click", function Typer(){
var index = 0;
var text ="Hello there, I'm a college student and I have a keen eye for whacky and cheeky animations.";
var speed = 60;
// SIMPLY ADD THE LINE BELOW
document.getElementById("typing_Text").textContent = "";
function textEffect() {
    if (index < text.length) {
        document.getElementById("typing_Text").textContent += text.charAt(index);
        index++;
        setTimeout(textEffect, speed);
    }
    
} 
textEffect();
```

}, {once : true});

Answer (score 1):

You should clear the original value on start of the typing effect.

I took the liberty to clean up your code a bit:

```js
document.getElementById("div_Container")
 .addEventListener("click", typeSlow, {once: true});
 
function typeSlow() {
  const text = [..."Hello there, I'm a college student and "+
  "I have a keen eye for whacky and cheeky animations."];
  const speed = 60;
   const typingTxt = document.getElementById("typing_Text");
   // clear on start
   typingTxt.textContent = ``;
   const runEffect = () => {
     if (text.length) {
       typingTxt.textContent += text.shift();
       return setTimeout( runEffect, speed );
     }
     console.log(`all done`)
   };
   runEffect();
}
```

```html
<div id="div_Container" class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-start">
  <p id="typing_Text">Click here to learn about me. </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you put the function definition where it wants a function to call. So you should move `function Typer()`... outside of the `addEventListener` or make it into an anonymous/arrow function. Secondly add `document.getElementById("typing_Text").textContent = '';` before calling `textEffect()` to remove the previous text.

Answer (score -3):

try this:

```
function textEffect() {
    if (index < text.length) {
        document.getElementById("typing_Text").innerText+= text.charAt(index);
        index++;
        setTimeout(textEffect, speed);
    }
    
}
textEffect();
```

Comment: Dont' just post code. Explain what you have done that answers the question

Comment: This doesn't even work.

Comment: this is thesame i posted my friend :) thanks for trying

Comment: @Techgorilla i just changed `textContent` to `innerText`